# SOAP with MockitoJUnit is not working in java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, junit, mockito

```
@WebService(name = "ManageSearchDataPortType", targetNamespace = "https://abc/searchData", serviceName = "ManageSearchData", portName = "ManageSearchDataPort", wsdlLocation = "/WEB-INF/wsdl/ManageSearchData.wsdl")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
import com.xyz.SearchDataRequest;
import com.xyz.SearchDataResponse;

@XmlSeeAlso({ ObjectFactory.class, com.abc.ObjectFactory.class, com.abc..ObjectFactory.class, com.abc..ObjectFactory.class })
public class ManageSearchDataService {

    @WebResult(name = "searchDataResponse", partName = "searchDataResponse", targetNamespace = "https://abc/searchData")
    @WebMethod(action = "http://example.com/wsdl/ManageABC/2008/10/22#searchData")
    public SearchDataResponse searchData(@WebParam(name = "searchDataRequest", partName = "searchDataRequest", targetNamespace = "https://abc/searchData")
        SearchDataRequest searchDataRequest) {
        System.out.println(" searchData Methodthod");

    }

     public void test();
     {
     System.out.println("TEST  Method");
     }
    }
```

Below is my **junit mockito** test class contains the test method i.e doSomething. Here i'm trying to mack ManageSearchDataService class which shown above contains searchData and test method, But

> searchData not being called by mock object

and normal test method has been called successfully. 
**searchData is my WebMethod as you can see the method.**

HeaderClass is just normal call which contains getMPLNHeader static method.

Please anyone have any idea how to do this let me know.

```
package com.test;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;    
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import com.xyz.SearchDataRequest;
import com.aaa.ManageSearchDataService;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class JunitTestClass {
    @Mock ManageSearchDataService mockObj ;

    @Test
    public void doSomething() {
        SearchDataRequest searchDataRequest= new SearchDataRequest();
        searchDataRequest.setStandardHeader(HeaderClass.getMPLNHeader("ASV"));
         mockObj.searchData(searchDataRequest); // not Working 
         mockObj.test();      // this working fine printing data
    }

    }
```

Comment: It is the expected behaviour for mock objects . They will not call the method but will give you the result which you have mocked . `mockobj.when(methodname).then(result)`

Answer (score 0):

You should not mock the class you want to test. You mock all other classes/objects except the class you want to test.

Comment: Do you have any example?

Answer (score 0):

As people already pointed out, mocking `ManageSearchDataService` doesn't make any sense. You are creating a mock object of your service and then test that mock, this isn't telling you anything about your service. Mocking is for dependencies, for example, if your service used another object to load data from a database, then mocking this would be a great idea for a unit test (because otherwise, your test would fail if the DB is down - even if the code it completely ok).

Mocking allows you to test one single unit by "simulating" all of its dependencies, so you don't have to rely on them being ok (that's the problem of other unit tests), because you simulate it in a way as if they were ok (or not, if you want to test error handling in your unit).

Since your class does not contain any dependencies like this at all (it doesn't actually do anything besides printing) there is nothing you could or should mock here.